# Regular Expression to validate empty fields allowing space with characters only

Tags: javascript

I have a form that use a regular expression that validate characters only alongwith whitespace, but I have a problem, this doesn't validate empty fields. My expression regular is this :

```
regex = /^\s*[a-zA-Z ]{2,30}$/;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to validate an empty field as well, you can provide an alternative for the whole pattern by putting `|^$` onto the end, thus matching the empty string too (that is, match the position at the beginning of the string, immediately followed by the position at the end of the string):

```html
<form>
<input pattern="^\s*[a-zA-Z ]{2,30}$|^$">
<button>submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: CertainPerformance i followed your suggestion but it not works for me. regex posted by me is work fine but when form field is empty and i press submit then regex posted by me is not work .

Comment: Press "Run code snippet" in the answer - it looks to perform as intended. It accepts the empty string, and it also accepts alphabetical word characters (repeated 2-30 times).

Comment: Thanks. its perfect.